# Automatically encrypting text editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, cryptography, tkinter

I have written an automatically encrypting text editor ([github link](https://github.com/1f604/sedit)). The reasons that I wrote this program instead of using vim + gpg are:

1. It's more convenient than vim + gpg (user only needs to enter password once).
2. It's more secure than vim + gpg (see CVE-2010-2547 and CVE-2019-12735).
3. User cannot accidentally change the password of the file.
4. My program checks to see that the file written to disk can be decrypted again.
5. My program makes a copy of the file every time it is written to disk, and checks that the copy is bit-for-bit identical to the original, in order to protect against disk sector corruption.

The reason I'm asking for a code review is to make sure I haven't messed up these properties somehow (especially the crypto, that's the part I'm most worried about), and also I would like to know what I can do to improve the security and reliability of my program against the most common threats such as bad input parsing (the same kind of errors as the Vim and GPG vulnerabilities mentioned above), disk sector failures and memory errors (due to not using ECC RAM). I also assume that I cannot defend against an adversary who is already running a program on the machine that can read the clipboard, log keystrokes, or read my process's memory. I also assume that python, tkinter, and pynacl are not backdoored, since the packages (other than python) are not signed.

If you don't have time to read through all the code, the most important functions I'd like to have reviewed are `encrypt`, `decrypt`, and `savefile`.

Crypto functions (`cryptotest.py`):

```py
import os
import base64
import nacl.pwhash
import nacl.secret
import nacl.utils

def _keygen(password: str): #key generation algorithm, not used outside this file
    """
    Takes a password string and returns a key.

    We don't need to salt the password since we're not storing it anywhere in any form.

    Parameters are hardcoded so you don't have to store or pass them.
    """
    password = password.encode('utf-8')
    kdf = nacl.pwhash.argon2i.kdf
    salt = b'1234567812345678' #salt must be exactly 16 bytes long
    ops = 4 #OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE
    mem = 33554432 #MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE

    return kdf(nacl.secret.SecretBox.KEY_SIZE, password, salt,
                 opslimit=ops, memlimit=mem)

def encrypt(plaintext: str, password: str) -> bytes:
    """
        pynacl includes the nonce (iv), tag, and ciphertext in the result from box.encrypt.

        According to the pynacl docs, the returned value will be exactly 40 bytes longer
        than the plaintext as it contains the 24 byte random nonce and the 16 byte MAC.
    """
    plaintext = plaintext.encode('utf-8')
    key = _keygen(password)
    box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(key)
    encrypted = box.encrypt(plaintext)
    return encrypted

def decrypt(encrypted: bytes, password: str) -> str:
    """
        We first decrypt the ciphertext using pynacl into a bytes object.

        We then use Python's UTF-8 decoder to convert that to a string.

        This function is only used in sopen.py. It is not used in screate.py.

        WARNING: This function NEEDS to be wrapped in a try-catch block, because decryption and decoding can and will raise exceptions.
    """
    key = _keygen(password)
    box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(key)
    plaintext = box.decrypt(encrypted)
    plaintextstring = plaintext.decode('utf-8')
    return plaintextstring
```

Create file function (`screate.py`):

```py
import os, sys, getpass
from cryptotest import encrypt

def getpassword() -> str:
    """
        This function has been manually tested.

        It successfully detects and exits when user enters a blank password,
        or when the user enters 2 passwords that don't match.
    """
    password1 = getpass.getpass("Enter a password: ")
    password2 = getpass.getpass("Enter the password again: ")
    if password1 != password2:
        print("Passwords do not match.")
        exit(1)
    if not password1:
        print("YOU MUST ENTER A PASSWORD!")
        exit(1)
    return password1

def createfile(filename: str) -> str:
    # create the file
    print("You will now be asked to enter a password for the new file.")
    try:
        password = getpassword()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        exit(1)
    try:
        with open(filename, 'xb') as f:
            ciphertext = encrypt("You can write your stuff in this file.", password)
            f.write(ciphertext)
            print("File " + filename + " was successfully created.")
            print("You can open the file with the following command:")
            print("    python3 sopen.py " + filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("An error occurred while creating the file. See above.")
        exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: screate.py filename")
        exit(0)
    fn = sys.argv[1]
    fn = os.path.abspath(fn) # just for insurance.
    createfile(fn)
```

Open file function (`sopen.py`):

```py
import sys
import os.path, getpass
import shutil
import filecmp
import random

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

TEAL = '#008080'
BROWN = '#800000'
GREY = '#808080'

def goodmsg(msg):
    print(bcolors.OKGREEN + msg + bcolors.ENDC)

def badmsg(msg):
    print(bcolors.FAIL + msg + bcolors.ENDC)

def error_out(msg: str):
    badmsg("Error: " + msg)
    getpass.getpass("Press enter to exit.") # This is to capture the user's password if he enters it inadvertently.
    exit(1)

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    error_out("You must use Python 3")

from cryptotest import encrypt, decrypt

class WindowManager(object):
    def getSearchboxContents(self):
        return self.searchbox.get()

    def getTextboxContents(self):
        return self.text.get("1.0", "end-1c")

    def savefile(self, event=None):
        """
            When we save a file, we need to make sure it can be decrypted again.

            To this end, we first try to save it in a tmp file, once that succeeds, 
            we then replace the original with the tmp file.
        """
        plaintext = self.getTextboxContents()
        self.curSavedFileContents = plaintext
        # We need to check that we can open the file again. If not, we need to re-save the file.
        # This loop exits once we've confirmed that we can decrypt the file we've just saved, or when we've tried 10 times.
        # To this end, we use a temporary file so that we don't lose the original.
        tempfilename = self.filename + ".tmp"
        success = False
        for i in range(10):
            # Since we immediately close the file, this should force a write to disk on save.
            with open(tempfilename, "wb") as f:
                f.write(encrypt(plaintext, self.password))
            # We then open the file to check if we can decrypt it.
            with open(tempfilename, "rb") as f:
                wholetext = f.read()
            try:
                if plaintext == decrypt(wholetext, self.password):
                    self.dirty = False
                    # We only change the window color after the file has been written to and closed successfully.
                    self.frame.configure(bg=TEAL)
                    goodmsg("Temp file saved successfully.")
                    success = True
                    break
            except Exception as e:
                badmsg(e)
                badmsg("Error encountered trying to decrypt/decode file, see above.")
                badmsg("This is attempt #" + str(i))
        if success:
            # successful, replace original file with tmp file.
            # we also update the backup copy, and check that they are bit-for-bit identical.
            os.remove(self.filename)
            os.rename(tempfilename, self.filename)
            goodmsg("Original successfully replaced by temp file.")
            backupfilename = self.filename+".backup"
            for _ in range(5):
                shutil.copy(self.filename, backupfilename)
                if not filecmp.cmp(self.filename, backupfilename):
                    badmsg("ERROR: backup file is not identical to original.")
                else:
                    goodmsg("Backup file successfully saved and checked.")
                    break
            else:
                badmsg("Warning: File was not backed up.")
        else:
            # failed, delete temporary file.
            os.remove(tempfilename)
            badmsg("ERROR: FILE NOT SAVED.")

    def checkUnsavedChanges(self, event=None):
        # check if saving
        # if not:
        if self.dirty:
            if messagebox.askyesno("Exit", "THERE ARE UNSAVED CHANGES! Do you want to quit the application?"):
                if messagebox.askokcancel("Exit", "THERE ARE UNSAVED CHANGES!! ARE YOU SURE you want to quit the application?"):
                    win = tk.Toplevel()
                    win.title('warning')
                    message = "This will delete stuff"
                    tk.Label(win, text=message).pack()
                    buttons = [
                        tk.Button(win, text='No!', command=win.destroy),
                        tk.Button(win, text='Delete', command=self.root.destroy),
                        tk.Button(win, text='Noo!', command=win.destroy),
                        tk.Button(win, text='Don\'t delete!!', command=win.destroy)
                    ]
                    random.shuffle(buttons)
                    for button in buttons:
                        button.pack()
        else:
            self.root.destroy()

    def ismodified(self, event):
        plaintext = self.getTextboxContents()
        if plaintext != self.curSavedFileContents:
            self.frame.configure(bg=BROWN)
            self.dirty = True
        else:
            self.frame.configure(bg=TEAL)
            self.dirty = False
        self.text.edit_modified(0)  # IMPORTANT - or <<Modified>> will not be called later.

    def on_focus_out(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.root:
            self.frame.configure(bg=GREY)

    def on_focus_in(self, event):
        if event.widget == self.root:
            if self.dirty:
                self.frame.configure(bg=BROWN)
            else:
                self.frame.configure(bg=TEAL)

    def focus_search(self, event):
        self.searchbox.focus()
        self.select_all_searchbox(event)

    def clear_highlights(self, event):
        self.in_search = False
        self.srch_idx = '1.0'
        self.text.tag_remove('found', '1.0', tk.END)
        self.text.tag_remove('found_cur', '1.0', tk.END)
        self.msglabel['text'] = ''

    def search_highlight(self, s):
        """
            Given a search string s, highlight all occurrances of it in the text.
        """
        self.text.tag_remove('found', '1.0', tk.END)
        if s:
            idx = '1.0'
            while 1:
                idx = self.text.search(s, idx, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
                if not idx: break
                lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(s))
                self.text.tag_add('found', idx, lastidx)
                idx = lastidx
            self.text.tag_config('found', background='magenta') #firefox search highlight colors
            self.text.tag_raise("sel") # allow highlighted text to be seen over search highlights

    def find_next(self, needle):
        self.text.tag_remove('found_cur', '1.0', tk.END)
        idx = self.text.search(needle, self.srch_idx, nocase=1, stopindex=tk.END)
        if not idx:
            self.srch_idx = '1.0'
            self.msglabel['text'] = 'No more search results.'
            return
        self.msglabel['text'] = ''
        lastidx = '%s+%dc' % (idx, len(needle))
        self.srch_idx = lastidx
        self.text.tag_add('found_cur', idx, lastidx)
        self.text.tag_config('found_cur', foreground='red', background='green') #firefox search highlight colors
        self.text.tag_raise("sel") # allow highlighted text to be seen over search highlights
        self.text.see(idx) # scroll the textbox to where the found text is.

    def text_search(self, event):
        needle = self.getSearchboxContents()
        if not self.in_search:
            self.in_search = True
            self.search_highlight(needle)
        self.find_next(needle)

    # This is to move the cursor to the end of the line when you click on some empty space at the end of the line.
    # Default behavior is really annoying as it moves the cursor to the beginning of the next line if you click past half of the whitespace.
    def on_text_click(self, event):
        line = event.x
        column = event.y
        index = self.text.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
        self.text.mark_set("insert", index)

    # Select all the text in textbox
    def select_all(self, event):
        self.text.tag_add(tk.SEL, "1.0", tk.END)
        return 'break'

    # Select all the text in searchbox
    def select_all_searchbox(self, event):
        self.searchbox.select_range(0, tk.END)
        return 'break'

    # Select current line in textbox
    def select_line(self, event):
        tk.current_line = self.text.index(tk.INSERT)
        self.text.tag_add(tk.SEL, "insert linestart", "insert lineend+1c")
        return 'break'
        #after(interval, self._highlight_current_line)

    def __init__(self, root, filename, contents, password):
        # initialize "global" variables
        # These variables refer to the elements inside the UI
        # For example, self.text refers to the main text box, self.searchbox refers to the search box, and so on.
        self.root = root
        self.filename = filename
        self.curSavedFileContents = contents
        self.password = password
        self.dirty = False
        self.frame = tk.Frame(root, bg=TEAL)
        self.text = tkst.ScrolledText(
            master=self.frame,
            wrap='word',  # wrap text at full words only
            width=80,      # characters
            height=30,      # text lines
            bg='beige',        # background color of edit area
            undo=True
        )
        self.searchframe = tk.Frame(root)
        self.searchlabel = tk.Label(self.searchframe, text='Search text:')
        self.searchbox = tk.Entry(self.searchframe)
        saveframe = tk.Frame(root)
        self.msglabel = tk.Label(saveframe, text='')

        # initialize text editor window UI
        self.root.wm_title("sedit")
        self.frame.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
        self.text.bind('<<Modified>>', self.ismodified)
        self.root.bind("<FocusIn>", self.on_focus_in)
        self.root.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)
        self.searchlabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.searchbox.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill='both')
        self.msglabel.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        self.searchframe.pack(fill=tk.X)
        button = tk.Button(saveframe, text="Save", command=self.savefile, padx=8, pady=8)
        button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
        saveframe.pack(fill=tk.X)
        # the padx/pady space will form a frame
        self.text.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=8, pady=8)
        self.text.insert('insert', contents)
        self.frame.configure(bg=TEAL)
        # On Mac, Command binds to the cmd key. On Windows it binds to the ctrl key.
        self.root.bind_all("<Command-w>", self.checkUnsavedChanges)
        self.root.bind_all("<Command-s>", self.savefile)
        self.text.bind("<Command-a>", self.select_all)
        self.text.bind("<Command-l>", self.select_line)
        self.in_search = False
        self.srch_idx = '1.0'
        self.text.bind("<Command-f>", self.focus_search)
        self.searchbox.bind("<Return>", self.text_search)
        self.root.bind("<Escape>", self.clear_highlights)
        self.searchbox.bind("<Command-a>", self.select_all_searchbox)
        self.root.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_text_click)
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.checkUnsavedChanges)  # root is your root window





def openfile(filename: str, password: str):
    #1. Open file and try to decrypt it.
    with open(filename,"rb") as f:
        s = f.read()
    contents = decrypt(s,password) # An exception here is fine as we can terminate here no problems.

    #2. Main window setup
    root=tk.Tk()
    WindowManager(root, filename, contents, password)

    #3. main loop
    root.mainloop()





if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        error_out("You must supply exactly one command line argument to open.py")

    filename = sys.argv[1]
    filename = os.path.abspath(filename) # just for insurance.

    # Check if file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        error_out("File not found.")

    goodmsg("sedit: Found file "+filename+".")

    password = getpass.getpass("Enter the password to decrypt the file: ")

    # All these GUI imports take a while, so we only do it after the user enters the right password.
    # This is to allow the user to enter the password immediately after starting this program.
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

    openfile(filename, password)
```

The `screate.py` and `sopen.py` files are intended to be run on their own, with a file name supplied as parameter. The user first creates a file using `screate.py filename` then he opens it with `sopen.py filename`, which will open the GUI. The keyboard shortcuts for the GUI are as follows:

- Ctrl-s to save file
- Ctrl-w to close editor
- Ctrl-a to select all
- Ctrl-l to select current line
- Ctrl-f to enter search mode and search text
- Esc to exit search mode

Comment: _the packages (other than python) are not signed_ - They are on most versions of Linux package manager, including apt, during download. Not so much once they hit the hard drive.

Comment: There isn't too much to be seen when it comes to encryption. It uses NaCl and a password hash. Fine. I think quoting two security advisories to dismiss Vim + GPG is a bit shallow though. Any runtime will have security advisories.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Are you saying that Python (a language runtime) is comparable to Vim or GPG (applications written in C) in terms of vulnerability to exploitation? As far as I can see in my program there are 3 significant places for exploitation: pynacl's MAC verifier, pynacl's decryptor, and Python's UTF-8 decoder. I am under the impression that bugs in an application are usually much more likely to be due to a programming error in the application itself, or a library the application uses, rather than the language runtime that the application is running on. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: My comment is not a criticism on Python, which is fine for crypto, as long as native functions are used where side channel attacks and such are concerned (those are tricky to avoid in higher level languages). And for parsing structures and such (a major part of the functionality in PGP) I'd prefer a higher level language with memory protection. My point was that dismissing libraries because of bugs is dangerous. If you create your own, you will create your own bugs, possibly even dupes of earlier bugs.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the first of those two CVEs. Firstly, GnuPG 2.0.16 is kinda ancient at this point. Secondly, and more importantly, that vulnerability related specifically to GPGSM; which is the S/MIME engine of the GnuPG Project (as opposed to GPG, which is the OpenPGP engine). The vast majority of GnuPG users are also OpenPGP users and not S/MIME users, so they would not have been affected by this. Even back in the day when that CVE meant something.